# Where in the Android source code does it display the app switcher?

Tags: android, android-source

I have been reading through some of the Android AOSP code as a side project, and it occurred to me that I had no idea where the code was to show the app switcher. I have grepped the source tree and done some Internet searches, but to no avail. Can somebody please point me in the right direction (file/directory/class name, etc.) I am pretty new to this, so please bear with me.

Specifically, I'm interested in the part of the code that detects a long press of Home and causes the app switcher UI to be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Home button, Long press of home key, power key are all handled in `frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java`

You can check  `handleLongPressOnHome` function in above source where RecentApplicationsDialog is being shown.

The function I have mentioned is from ICS code.